# Request not routed on CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I've got a working CodeIgniter website on my machine. However, when I move it to the live server, it says that it is unable to determine what should be displayed. I checked the paths, base URL and .htaccess and everything seems to be correct. How can I find out what the problem is?

Edit: This is the content of routes.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = "";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message displayed in your browser, or a link to the live site?

Comment: Can you post what you have in your /config/routes.php ?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the main post, but there's nothing special in there since I'm not using any default controller. The url I'm calling specifies a controller (view) and a method (harbin).

Comment: Hmmm - so I'm getting the same error regardless of what URL segments are passed to http://pogopixels.com/pics/ - When CI attempts to push out the HTTP header there is a PHP error caused by the stuff you have echoed out at the top of the page. Have you modified index.php to print those paths?

Comment: OK - So I've modified a local instance of CI on my Mac so that I print out a couple of lines at the bottom of the index.php (lines 155, 156 and 157). When I do this it replicates the error you get.

Comment: Yes I was printing these lines to check that the paths were correct (and they are). I've now removed them but it didn't fix the issue. I'm still getting the same error: "Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file." Is there any way to diagnose these errors with CodeIgniter? Perhaps a way to print the route it is following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message does suggest that CI is attempting to fall back to the default controller which you have not specified. Assuming that the controller you are calling does exist this suggests that the problem might be to do with the server configuration and the way it is handling the URLs.

Try changing the URI Protocol in the config.php file (line 47). The default is 'AUTO' which works most of the time, but I have known servers that didn't like this. The comments in the file suggest various values you could try.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks! I changed the value from AUTO to PATH_INFO and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

From the code supplied above, there is no default controller. CI requires a default controller is set, hence the error message.

If you have set one, then the problem isn't related to the above code.

Comment: Well a default controller is not needed since I'm explicitly calling a controller (view). In that case, how can I figure out why it's not finding the "view" controller? It's working fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your default controller in routes.php, for example

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home"; // home is the name of the controller
```